# How to fetch records between two dates in mongodb using aggregation in springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to fetch all records in mongodb that they are between two specific dates.
In springboot I use this aggregation :

```
newAggregation(
    project()
        .andExpression("year(finishTimestamp)").as("year")
        .andExpression("month(finishTimestamp)").as("month")
        .andExpression("dayOfMonth(finishTimestamp)").as("day")
    match(Criteria.where("finishTimestamp").gte(startDate).lte(endDate)),
    group(fields().and("year").and("month").and("day"))
        .count().as("cnt")
);
```

`startDate` and `endDate` both are type of `java.util.Date`.
in above aggregation mongodb ignores match operation completely.

in springboot I use aggregation to fetch data in this way :

```
AggregationResults <Map> server = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
    "someName", Map.class);
```

What's wrong with this aggregation?

Comment: move the match stage before project stage

Comment: @Veeram Thanks so much,it works perfectly,please answer the question so I can accept your answer.